# How do I correctly import packages with py.test?

Tags: python, import, pytest, python-3.4

I have the following layout:

```
/spamalot
    /spam
        __init__.py
        spam.py
        /spam_on_eggs
            __init__.py
            spam_on_eggs.py
    /tests

        test_spam.py
```

Spam just so happens to be a flask application.

Within `spam.py` I have

```
import spam_on_eggs.spam_on_eggs as eggs
# Other Flask setup & application code here.
```

And this works fine - from the `spamalot` directory I'm able to run `python spam/spam.py`

However, when I start to throw tests into the mix, it's not as awesome.

In my `test_spam.py` file I have:

```
import spam.spam
test_client = spam.spam.app.test_client()

def test_it_fails():
     assert False
```

However, rather than failing where I would expect, it fails on the import line:

```
/spamalot/ $ py.test
# some output
E    ImportError
```

I can fix this by putting `__init__.py` in my `/tests` folder, but then I get a different ImportError:

```
spam/spam.py:1: in <module>
>    import spam_on_eggs.spam_on_eggs as eggs
E    ImportError: No module named 'spam_on_eggs'
```

I can solve *that* one by changing the line to:

```
from spam.spam_on_eggs import spam_on_eggs
```

Which allows me to test **but** then I break my ability to run `$ python spam/spam.py` - because I get

```
ImportError: no module named 'spam'
```

Obviously I have a gap in my understanding of how module imports work and how py.test works with this system.

What am I missing?

Is it even possible to have the layout I've described - and be able to run both py.test and my server from the spamalot directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

py.test will always use the shortest directory path with an `__init__.py` in it.

Put a `__init__.py` into spamalot and you can import `spamalot.spam.spam`.

Reference: [choosing a test layout](http://pytest.org/latest/#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules)

Comment: That would make spamalot into a module, no? That's not actually what I'm looking for - if I want my tests in the same module I'll just stick them as a submodule of spam

Comment: Also this did not actually work (`ImportError` as well)

Comment: This depends on the superdirectory of `spamalot`. Is there a `__init__.py`? Have a look at the link. Also consider adding a path to `sys.path`.

Comment: spamalot is the project root (e.g. contains `.git` folder, `requirements.txt`, etc)